# How to read specific bytes from a binary MP3 file in Python?

Tags: python, mp3, binaryfiles, lame

I would learn to handle read and write binary data. I know that I can open a binary file with

```
f = open(myfile, mode='rb')
fb = f.read()
f.close()
return fb
```

How can I access and read the range $A7-$AC in a mp3 file with this structure:
[Lame mp3 Tags](http://gabriel.mp3-tech.org/mp3infotag.html)

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at Python's [`struct`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html?highlight=struct#module-struct) library for help with extracting binary data.

```
import struct

mp3_filename = r"my_mp3_file.mp3"

with open(mp3_filename, 'rb') as f_mp3:
    mp3 = f_mp3.read()
    entry = mp3[0xA7:0xAC+1]
    print struct.unpack("{}b".format(len(entry)), entry)
```

This would give you a list of integers such as:

```
(49, 0, 57, 0, 57, 0)
```

You pass a format string to tell Python how to intepret each of the bytes. In this example, they are all simply converted from bytes into integers. Each format specifier can have a repeat count, so for your example, the format string would be `"6b"`. If you wanted to decode this as words, you would simply change the format specifier, there is a full table of options to help you: [Struct format characters](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html?highlight=struct#format-characters)

To convert these to zeros, you would need to close the file and reopen it for writing. Build a new output as follows:

```
import struct

mp3_filename = r"my_mp3_file.mp3"
zeros = "\0\0\0\0\0\0"

with open(mp3_filename, 'rb') as f_mp3:
    mp3 = f_mp3.read()
    entry = mp3[0xA7:0xAC+1]
    print struct.unpack("{}B".format(len(entry)), entry)

    if entry != zeros:
        print "non zero"

with open(mp3_filename, 'wb') as f_mp3:
    f_mp3.write(mp3[:0xA7] + zeros + mp3[0xAD:])
```

FYI: There are ready made Python libraries that are able to extract tag information from MP3 files. Take a look at something like the `id3reader` package.

Comment: Thanks a lot. The resulting integers are perfect for me. I wish only to check if there are not 0. But how can I replace such bytes e.g with zeros and write it back to the file?

Comment: IMHO, the id3reader package is not the right for this while these are fields from the lame tags, not the id3 tags.

Comment: You will need to reopen the mp3 file in binary write mode and replace the section with zeros. I have updated the answer.